# How to get option set value from lookup field by using Javascript, OData endpoint

Tags: javascript, odata, dynamics-crm

I can retrieve any text field value from Account and set the value to text field in Contact. But got `invalid type` when I tried to use the same code for option set field.

In this case, `parentcustomerid` is a lookup field in `Contact` which lookup to `Account`. `new_GroupofAccount` is option set Schema name in `Account` and `new_groupofaccountcontact` is option set field name in `Contact`. What I want to achieve if `parentcustomerid` got value, I want value of option set in `Account` to be reflect in `new_groupofaccountcontact` in `contact`. Both option set fields is using same global option set value.

This is my js code:

```js
function getOptionSet() {
  var accountId = null;
  try {
    accountId = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("parentcustomerid").getValue()[0].id;
  } catch (ex) {
    accountId = null;
  }
  if (accountId !== null) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/AccountSet(guid'" + accountId + "')?$select=new_GroupofAccount";
    req.open("GET", url, true);
    req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (req.readyState == 4) {
        var data = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
        // use data.d.WebSiteURL 
        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_groupofaccountcontact").setValue(data.d.new_GroupofAccount);
      }
    };
    req.send(null);
  }
}
```

Greatly appreciate for any helps. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `.setValue(data.d.new_GroupofAccount.Value);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the code is correct, just need to passing `Value` of option set retrieve from the OData Query like `.setValue(data.d.new_GroupofAccount.Value);`.

Hope this will benefit someone in future.